# My Checkboxes or Radio Buttons Do Not Align Properly?

Tags: html, css

I been working on a simple survey page to learn more about CSS and HTML. I keep running into this issue where my radio button values and my checkbox values do not align properly specifically for the "How did you pay for your trip?" section and "What is your favorite color"? section.

They are suppose to align like this:

How did you pay for your trip?

- Cash
- Check
- Other

```css
body {
  height: 920px;
  width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

#subtag {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 75px;
}

.container {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491800943052-1059ce1e1012?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=80");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  height: 920px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 920px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.box {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 890px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.textbox {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #80bfff;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.money {
  display: inline;
}

#submit {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #d6d4e0;
  width: 270px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #6b5b95;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

#submit:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">

    <h3> Villa's Traveling Survey </h3>
    <p id="subtag">
      If there is anything that we can do better please let us know by filling out the survey below </p>

    <form>
      <label for="fname"> Name: </label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="enter name" class="textbox">
      <br>
      <label for="email"> Email: </label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="enter email" class="textbox">
      <br>
      <label for="age"> Age: </label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="enter age" class="textbox">
      <p> Travel Destination: </p>
      <select name="country">
        <option disabled selected value="Select Your Travel Destination"> Select Your Travel Destination </option>
        <option value="Australia"> Australia</option>
        <option value="New Zealeand"> New Zealand </option>
        <option value="Thailand"> Thailand </option>
      </select>

      <p> How did you pay for your trip? </p>

      <label>
        <input type="radio" name= "trip" value = "check" class= "money">
        check<br>
    </label>

      <label>
        <input type="radio" name= "trip" value = "cash" class= "money">
        cash<br>
      </label>

      <label>
        <input type="radio" name= "trip" value = "other" class= "money">
        other
      </label>

      <p> How did you get to your travel destination? </p>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" placeholder="plane" value="plane" class="checkbox">Plane
      <input type="checkbox" placeholder="boat" value="boat" class="checkbox">Boat
      <input type="checkbox" placeholder="train" value="train" class="checkbox">Train
      <input type="checkbox" placeholder="other" value="other" class="checkbox">Other

      <p> What is your favorite color? </p>
      <label><input
         name="prefer"
         value="front-end-projects"
         type="checkbox"
         class="input-checkbox"
       />Front-end Projects</label
     >
     <br/>
     <label
      ><input
        name="prefer"
        value="front-end-projects"
        type="checkbox"
        class="input-checkbox"
      />back-end Projects</label
    >
    <br/>
    <label
     ><input
       name="prefer"
       value="front-end-projects"
       type="checkbox"
       class="input-checkbox"
     />love Projects</label
   >


      <p> Please enter any additional comments or suggestions </p>
      <textarea rows="5" cols="50" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter comments here"></textarea>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" id = "submit">
      </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Some of the solutions that I have tried is making the country class vertical-align middle. However, this does not work. I have also tried changing the display to inline block. However, it pushed all the values to one line.

Is there anything that I'm doing to cause this problem? Normally, a simple br tag will align the radio values. However, the values do not align correctly.

Any suggestions or comments will be helpful!

Below is the jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/fun_code11/9wvj130b/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `.box` class has the `text-align` set to center. So your labels are honoring that rule, as are the checkboxes. It only 'looks' weird because your label content are variable in length, so the shorter words become closer to the center.

There are a lot of ways to style this and I don't know what you need holistically, but a solution is to just wrap them in a container that will be centered by `.box` and reset the alignment, keep in mind that any white-space before the word is included too:

```
#money-container {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}

<div id="money-container">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name= "trip" value = "check" class= "money">check<br>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name= "trip" value = "cash" class= "money">cash<br>
  </label>

  <label>
   <input type="radio" name= "trip" value = "other" class= "money">other
  </label>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  height: 920px;
  width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

#subtag {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 75px;
}

.container {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491800943052-1059ce1e1012?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=80");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  height: 920px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 920px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.box {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 890px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.textbox {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #80bfff;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#submit {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #d6d4e0;
  width: 270px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #6b5b95;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

#submit:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#money-container {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">

    <h3> Villa's Traveling Survey </h3>
    <p id="subtag">
      If there is anything that we can do better please let us know by filling out the survey below </p>

    <form>
      <label for="fname"> Name: </label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="enter name" class="textbox">
      <br>
      <label for="email"> Email: </label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="enter email" class="textbox">
      <br>
      <label for="age"> Age: </label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="enter age" class="textbox">
      <p> Travel Destination: </p>
      <select name="country">
        <option disabled selected value="Select Your Travel Destination"> Select Your Travel Destination </option>
        <option value="Australia"> Australia</option>
        <option value="New Zealeand"> New Zealand </option>
        <option value="Thailand"> Thailand </option>
      </select>


      <p> How did you pay for your trip? </p>

      <div id="money-container">
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name= "trip" value = "check" class= "money">check<br></label>

        <label>
        <input type="radio" name= "trip" value = "cash" class= "money">cash<br></label>

        <label>
        <input type="radio" name= "trip" value = "other" class= "money">other</label>
      </div>

      <p> How did you get to your travel destination? </p>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" placeholder="plane" value="plane" class="checkbox">Plane
      <input type="checkbox" placeholder="boat" value="boat" class="checkbox">Boat
      <input type="checkbox" placeholder="train" value="train" class="checkbox">Train
      <input type="checkbox" placeholder="other" value="other" class="checkbox">Other

      <p> What is your favorite color? </p>
      <label><input
         name="prefer"
         value="front-end-projects"
         type="checkbox"
         class="input-checkbox"
       />Front-end Projects</label
     >
     <br/>
     <label
      ><input
        name="prefer"
        value="front-end-projects"
        type="checkbox"
        class="input-checkbox"
      />back-end Projects</label
    >
    <br/>
    <label
     ><input
       name="prefer"
       value="front-end-projects"
       type="checkbox"
       class="input-checkbox"
     />love Projects</label
   >


      <p> Please enter any additional comments or suggestions </p>
      <textarea rows="5" cols="50" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter comments here"></textarea>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" id = "submit">
      </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one parent div and apply the following CSS:

```
.chkcon{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```css
body{
    text-align:center;
}
.chkcon{
    background:red;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="chkcon">
<label>
    <input type="radio" name= "trip" value = "check" class= "money">
    check<br>
</label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name= "trip" value = "cash" class= "money">
    cash<br>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name= "trip" value = "other" class= "money">
    other
  </label>
</div>
<p> What is your favorite color? </p>
<div class="chkcon">
      <label><input
         name="prefer"
         value="front-end-projects"
         type="checkbox"
         class="input-checkbox"
       />Front-end Projects</label
     >
     <br/>
     <label
      ><input
        name="prefer"
        value="front-end-projects"
        type="checkbox"
        class="input-checkbox"
      />back-end Projects</label
    >
    <br/>
    <label
     ><input
       name="prefer"
       value="front-end-projects"
       type="checkbox"
       class="input-checkbox"
     />love Projects</label
   ></div>
</body>
```

```css
body {
  height: 920px;
  width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}
.chkcon{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
#subtag {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 75px;
}

.container {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491800943052-1059ce1e1012?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=80");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  height: 920px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 920px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.box {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 890px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.textbox {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #80bfff;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.money {
  display: inline;
}

#submit {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #d6d4e0;
  width: 270px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #6b5b95;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

#submit:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">

    <h3> Villa's Traveling Survey </h3>
    <p id="subtag">
      If there is anything that we can do better please let us know by filling out the survey below </p>

    <form>
      <label for="fname"> Name: </label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="enter name" class="textbox">
      <br>
      <label for="email"> Email: </label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="enter email" class="textbox">
      <br>
      <label for="age"> Age: </label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="enter age" class="textbox">
      <p> Travel Destination: </p>
      <select name="country">
        <option disabled selected value="Select Your Travel Destination"> Select Your Travel Destination </option>
        <option value="Australia"> Australia</option>
        <option value="New Zealeand"> New Zealand </option>
        <option value="Thailand"> Thailand </option>
      </select>

      <p> How did you pay for your trip? </p>
 <div class="chkcon">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name= "trip" value = "check" class= "money">
        check<br>
    </label>

      <label>
        <input type="radio" name= "trip" value = "cash" class= "money">
        cash<br>
      </label>

      <label>
        <input type="radio" name= "trip" value = "other" class= "money">
        other
      </label>
    </div>
      <p> How did you get to your travel destination? </p>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" placeholder="plane" value="plane" class="checkbox">Plane
      <input type="checkbox" placeholder="boat" value="boat" class="checkbox">Boat
      <input type="checkbox" placeholder="train" value="train" class="checkbox">Train
      <input type="checkbox" placeholder="other" value="other" class="checkbox">Other

      <p> What is your favorite color? </p>
 <div class="chkcon">
      <label><input
         name="prefer"
         value="front-end-projects"
         type="checkbox"
         class="input-checkbox"
       />Front-end Projects</label
     >
     <br/>
     <label
      ><input
        name="prefer"
        value="front-end-projects"
        type="checkbox"
        class="input-checkbox"
      />back-end Projects</label
    >
    <br/>
    <label
     ><input
       name="prefer"
       value="front-end-projects"
       type="checkbox"
       class="input-checkbox"
     />love Projects</label
   ></div>


      <p> Please enter any additional comments or suggestions </p>
      <textarea rows="5" cols="50" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter comments here"></textarea>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" id = "submit">
      </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  height: 920px;
  width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

#subtag {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 75px;
}

.container {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491800943052-1059ce1e1012?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=80");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  height: 920px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 920px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.box {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 890px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.textbox {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #80bfff;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#submit {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #d6d4e0;
  width: 270px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #6b5b95;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

#submit:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#money-container,#check-container {
    display: flex;
    text-align: left;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#money-container label {
    width: 100px;
    margin: auto;
}
#check-container label
{ 
  width: 150px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">

    <h3> Villa's Traveling Survey </h3>
    <p id="subtag">
      If there is anything that we can do better please let us know by filling out the survey below </p>

    <form>
      <label for="fname"> Name: </label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="enter name" class="textbox">
      <br>
      <label for="email"> Email: </label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="enter email" class="textbox">
      <br>
      <label for="age"> Age: </label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="enter age" class="textbox">
      <p> Travel Destination: </p>
      <select name="country">
        <option disabled selected value="Select Your Travel Destination"> Select Your Travel Destination </option>
        <option value="Australia"> Australia</option>
        <option value="New Zealeand"> New Zealand </option>
        <option value="Thailand"> Thailand </option>
      </select>


      <p> How did you pay for your trip? </p>

      <div id="money-container">
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name= "trip" value = "check" class= "money">check<br></label>

        <label>
        <input type="radio" name= "trip" value = "cash" class= "money">cash<br></label>

        <label>
        <input type="radio" name= "trip" value = "other" class= "money">other</label>
      </div>

      <p> How did you get to your travel destination? </p>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" placeholder="plane" value="plane" class="checkbox">Plane
      <input type="checkbox" placeholder="boat" value="boat" class="checkbox">Boat
      <input type="checkbox" placeholder="train" value="train" class="checkbox">Train
      <input type="checkbox" placeholder="other" value="other" class="checkbox">Other

      <p> What is your favorite color? </p>
      <div id="check-container">
      <label><input
         name="prefer"
         value="front-end-projects"
         type="checkbox"
         class="input-checkbox"
       />Front-end Projects</label
     >
     <br/>
     <label
      ><input
        name="prefer"
        value="front-end-projects"
        type="checkbox"
        class="input-checkbox"
      />back-end Projects</label
    >
    <br/>
    <label
     ><input
       name="prefer"
       value="front-end-projects"
       type="checkbox"
       class="input-checkbox"
     />love Projects</label
   >
</div>

      <p> Please enter any additional comments or suggestions </p>
      <textarea rows="5" cols="50" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter comments here"></textarea>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" id = "submit">
      </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The HTML will look like

```html
<label class="checkLabel">
  <input type="radio" name="trip" value="cash" class="money">
  <span>Cash</span>
</label>
```

And in your CSS

```css
.checkLabel {
  display: block;
}

.checkLabel input, .checkLabel span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

As you can see it will help you align items vertically in label

Comment: Unfortunately, I made those changes and it did not work. It made the alignment into more like a triangle.